# Trouble installing google assistant on a raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I am getting the following error when I run google-assistant-demo

```
OpenAlsaHandle PcmOpen: No such file or directory
[4571:4583:ERROR:audio_input_processor.cc(756)] Input error
ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {'is_muted': False}
ON_START_FINISHED
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
  {'is_fatal': True}
[4571:4586:ERROR:audio_input_processor.cc(756)] Input error
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
  {'is_fatal': True}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific regards when this occurs?

Comment: did you configure and test audio according to the official documentation ?
 https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/configure-audio

Answer (score 1):

I got this error a couple of times, assuming you have done everything described here and it is working: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/configure-audio

Do a `sudo reboot` to make sure there aren't multiple instances of the google-assistant-demo running.

Then if you are running the google-assistant-demo from a script (either start-up or manually) try running it without a `sudo` prefix, that fixed my problem!

See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44741508/3562522) for more detail about how I got it running smoothly from start-up

Answer (score 0):

Its an error due to improper alsa.conf configuration. You need to change it according to your audio setup.