# How to run a programme inside a virtual environment from a script

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, virtualenv, google-assistant-sdk

I have set up the google assistant sdk on my Raspberry Pi as shown here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample

Now in order to re-run the assistant I have worked out the two commands are

```
$ source env/bin/activate
```

and

```
(env) $ google-assistant-demo
```

however I want to automate this process into a script that I can call from `rc.local` (followed by an `&`) in order to make the assistant boot from start up.

However if I run a simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
source env/bin/activate
google-assistant-demo
```

the assistant does not run inside the environment
my environment path is `/home/pi/env/bin/activate`
How can I have it so the script starts the environment and then runs the assistant *inside* the virtual environment?

EDIT: In the end I went with the following method:

using this as a base :
https://youtu.be/ohUszBxuQA4?t=774 – thanks to Eric Parisot

You will need to [download the src file](https://mega.nz/#!T1AlCIrC!3PujVbbOCyZjgvn_OK4HlKYggwWRbwi8BEAgw5x126A) he uses and extract its contents into `/home/pi/src/`

However with a few changes.

I did not run `gassist.sh` as `sudo`, as it gave me the following error:

```
OpenAlsaHandle PcmOpen: No such file or directory
[7689:7702:ERROR:audio_input_processor.cc(756)] Input error
ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
{‘is_muted’: False}
ON_START_FINISHED
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
{‘is_fatal’: True}
[7689:7704:ERROR:audio_input_processor.cc(756)] Input error
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
{‘is_fatal’: True}
```

Fix: DO NOT run as `sudo`

If `gassist.sh` gives an error about `RPi.GPIO` you need to do https://youtu.be/ohUszBxuQA4?t=580:

```
$ cd /home/pi/env/bin
$ source activate
(env) $ pip install RPi.GPIO
(env) $ deactivate
```

And then I did `sudo nano /etc/profile`
and the appended this to the end:

```
#Harvs was here on 24/06/17
if pidof -x "gassist.sh" >/dev/null; then
    echo ""
    echo "/etc/profile says:"
    echo "An instance of Google Assistant is already running, will not start again"
    echo ""
else
    echo "Starting Google Assistant..."
    echo "If you are seeing this, perhaps you have SSH within seconds of reboot"
    /home/pi/src/gassist.sh &
fi
```

And now it works perfectly, and inside the virtual enviroment :)

Comment: Does `source /home/pi/env/bin/activate` help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env python on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with the following method:

using this as a base : https://youtu.be/ohUszBxuQA4?t=774 – thanks to Eric Parisot

However with a few changes.

You will need to [download the src file](https://mega.nz/#!T1AlCIrC!3PujVbbOCyZjgvn_OK4HlKYggwWRbwi8BEAgw5x126A) he uses and extract its contents into `/home/pi/src/`

I did not run `gassist.sh` as `sudo`, as it gave me the following error:

```
OpenAlsaHandle PcmOpen: No such file or directory
[7689:7702:ERROR:audio_input_processor.cc(756)] Input error
ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
{‘is_muted’: False}
ON_START_FINISHED
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
{‘is_fatal’: True}
[7689:7704:ERROR:audio_input_processor.cc(756)] Input error
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
{‘is_fatal’: True}
```

Fix: DO NOT run as sudo

If `gassist.sh` gives an error about `RPi.GPIO` you need to do https://youtu.be/ohUszBxuQA4?t=580:

```
$ cd /home/pi/env/bin
$ source activate
(env) $ pip install RPi.GPIO
(env) $ deactivate
```

And then I did `sudo nano /etc/profile` and the appended this to the end:

```
#Harvs was here on 24/06/17
if pidof -x "gassist.sh" >/dev/null; then
    echo ""
    echo "/etc/profile says:"
    echo "An instance of Google Assistant is already running, will not start again"
    echo ""
else
    echo "Starting Google Assistant..."
    echo "If you are seeing this, perhaps you have SSH within seconds of reboot"
    /home/pi/src/gassist.sh &
fi
```

And now it works perfectly, and inside the virtual enviroment, and in boot to CLI mode! :)

Answer (score 2):

found solution here :https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45089

Create a startup shell script in your root directory (I named mine "launch"), make it executable too :

```
sudo nano launch.sh
```

I wrote it that way :

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/pi/env/bin/activate
/home/pi/env/bin/google-assistant-demo
```

Save the file

Edit the LXDE-pi autostart file

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Add this to the bottom of that file

```
./launch.sh
```

reboot

Comment: This worked really well thanks, much better than many complex solutions I have seen elsewhere. one minor change is that (I think) you have to chmod +x the script in order for it to work! Also despite the first line, it does not actually run the script *inside* the env, but it still works, so oh well!

Comment: One issue with the method is that it doesnt work in boot to CLI mode, only boot to GUI

Comment: Another method here to start on CLI : ://youtu.be/ohUszBxuQA4

Answer (score 0):

Scripts run from `rc.local` execute in the root directory (or possibly in the home directory of the `root` user, depending on the distro, I think?)

The easy fix is to code the full path to the environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/pi/env/bin/activate
google-assistant-demo
# or maybe /home/pi/google-assistant-demo
```

There is no need to explicitly background anything in `rc.local`